# 7.2.The program in the Record structure has a compiler error

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors

I want to write the following program, but I get an error. What should I do? The contents of the program.

1. Record input(void) : Input from standard input (keyboard) to
   structure
2. void output(Record) : Output of structure contents to standard
   output (displayed on display)
3. int main(): Defines the structure variable data. Call input and
   output once, respectively.
4. The above program is further modified (modification of main function
   and addition of function int getage(Record)) to correspond to data
   for two people.
5. Change the structure variable data to a structure array with a
   number of elements 2 and use the prog02a.c function input and output
   created in the previous question to input data from standard input
   and output to standard output for two people (no changes are made to
   the input or output function).
6. In addition, using a structure element as an argument, create a
   function int getage(Record) to return the full age at the time of
   the reference date, call this function from main, so that the age of
   each person is also displayed. However, the record date is October
   1, 2020 and will be given by macro.

prog02b.c source code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "prog01.h"
#define YEAR 2019
#define MANTH 10
#define DAY 1

Record input (void);

void output (Record);

int getage (Record);

int main () {
  
  int i;
  
  Record data [2];

  printf ("-------- data entry -------- \ n");

  for (i = 0; i <2; i ++) {
    
    printf ("% dth", i + 1);
    
    data [i] = input ();
  }

  printf ("\ n -------- data output -------- \ nage base date:% d year% d month% d day \ n", YEAR, MANTH, DAY);
  
  for (i = 0; i <2; i ++) {
    printf ("% dth data: \ n", i + 1);
    
    output (data [i]);

    printf ("First name (last name):% s \ n First name (first name):% s \ n Date of birth:% d year% d month% d day \ n Age:% d \ n", data.familyname, data. firstname, data.birthday [0], data.birth>
  }
    
  return 0;
}

Record input (void) {
  Record data;
  
  printf ("Enter data \ n");
  
  printf ("first name (surname)->");
  scanf ("% s", data.familyname);

  printf ("name (first name)->");
  scanf ("% s", data.firstname);
  
  
  printf ("Year of birth (AD)->");
  scanf ("% d", & data.birthday [0]);
  
  printf ("month of birth->");
  scanf ("% d", & data.birthday [1]);
  
  printf ("date of birth->");
  scanf ("% d", & data.birthday [2]);

  printf ("Gender (0: Male, 1: Female)->");
  scanf ("% d", & data.gender);

  return data;
}

void output (Record data) {
  printf ("First name (last name):% s \ n First name (first name):% s \ n Date of birth:% d year% d month% d day", data.familyname, data.firstname, data.birthday [0] , data.birthday [1], data.>
  
  if (data.gender == 0)
    {printf ("(male) \ n");
  
    } else {printf ("(female) \ n");
  }
}

int getage (Record data) {
  if (data.birthday [1]> = MANTH) return YEAR-data.birthday [0] -1;
  else return YEAR-data.birthday [0];
}
```

prog01.h

```
typedef struct
    char familyname[20]; // first name (last name)
    char firstname[20];  // name (first name)
    int birthday[3];     //Birthday (Element 0: A.D. Element 1: Month Element 2: Day)
    int gender;        //Gender (0:Male, 1:Female)
Record.
```

copile error

```
prog02b.c: In function ‘main’:
prog02b.c: 35: 103: error: ‘(Record *) & data’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
   35 |):% s \ n Date of Birth:% d Years% d Months% d Days \ n Age:% d \ n ", data.familyname, data.firstname, data.birthday [0], data.birthday [ 1], data.birthday [2], getage (data [i]));
      | ^
      |->
prog02b.c: 35: 120: error: ‘(Record *) & data’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
   35 | � days:% d years% d months% d days \ n age:% d \ n ", data.familyname, data.firstname, data.birthday [0], data.birthday [1], data.birthday [ 2], getage (data [i]));
      | ^
      |->
prog02b.c: 35: 136: error: ‘(Record *) & data’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
   35 | �% d days \ n age:% d \ n ", data.familyname, data.firstname, data.birthday [0], data.birthday [1], data.birthday [2], getage (data [i] ]));
      | ^
      |->
prog02b.c: 35: 154: error: ‘(Record *) & data’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
   35 |% d \ n ", data.familyname, data.firstname, data.birthday [0], data.birthday [1], data.birthday [2], getage (data [i]));
      | ^
      |->
prog02b.c: 35: 172: error: ‘(Record *) & data’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
   35 | ame, data.firstname, data.birthday [0], data.birthday [1], data.birthday [2], getage (data [i]));
      | ^
      |->
```

"| ^" Every this error point is data.familyname, data.firstname, data.birthday[0], data.birthday[1], data.birthday[2].

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include comments on the lines of the shown code where you get the errors.

Comment: There is no earthly way that header file can possibly compile. Even fixing that, in `main` `data` is declared as an array `[2]` of `Record`. So when you put `data.familyname` etc. in an argument list for `printf`, which one did you have in mind? `data[0]` or `data[1]` ? Finally, *all* of the space-separated escape sequences are *wrong*. What abomination of tutorials is teaching this anyway?

Comment: As a hint, please try to read the error message and try to decipher what it can mean. Especially the "‘... data’ is a pointer" bit. Why do you think it say that? What *is* `data`? How do you use `data` at that point in the code?

Comment: I don't know how you copy/pasted your code, but it is full of `\ n`s instead of `\n`s and many other similar problems with `\\` escapes sequences

Comment: Instead of copying your whole assignment which does not add any value to any reader in case of compilation errors you could tell us which part of those error messages are not clear for you. They are rather straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues. I corrected them so your program compiles without errors nor warnings.

But I have no idea if it actually does what it should do.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  char familyname[20]; // first name (last name)
  char firstname[20];  // name (first name)
  int birthday[3];     //Birthday (Element 0: A.D. Element 1: Month Element 2: Day)
  int gender;        //Gender (0:Male, 1:Female)
}
Record;

#define YEAR 2019
#define MANTH 10
#define DAY 1

Record input(void);
void output(Record);
int getage(Record);

int main()
{
  int i;
  Record data[2];

  printf("-------- data entry --------\n");

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("%dth", i + 1);
    data[i] = input();
  }

  printf("\n -------- data output -------- \nage base date:%d year%d month%d day\n", YEAR, MANTH, DAY);

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    printf("%dth data:\n", i);
    output(data[i]);

    printf("First name (last name): %s\n First name (first name): %s\n Date of birth: %d year %d month %d day\n age: %d\n", data[i].familyname, data[i].firstname, data[i].birthday[0], data[i].birthday[1], data[i].birthday[2], getage(data[i]));
  }

  return 0;
}

Record input(void) {
  Record data;

  printf("Enter data \n");

  printf("first name (surname)->");
  scanf("%s", data.familyname);

  printf("name (first name)->");
  scanf("%s", data.firstname);


  printf("Year of birth (AD)->");
  scanf("%d", &data.birthday[0]);

  printf("month of birth->");
  scanf("%d", &data.birthday[1]);

  printf("date of birth->");
  scanf("%d", &data.birthday[2]);

  printf("Gender (0: Male, 1: Female)->");
  scanf("%d", &data.gender);

  return data;
}

void output(Record data) {
  printf("First name (last name):%s \n First name (first name):%s \n Date of birth:%d year %d month %d day", data.familyname, data.firstname, data.birthday[0], data.birthday[1], data.birthday[2]);

    if (data.gender == 0)
    {
      printf("(male) \n");
    }
    else 
    {
      printf("(female) \n");
    }
}

int getage(Record data) {
  if (data.birthday[1] >= MANTH) return YEAR - data.birthday[0] - 1;
  else return YEAR - data.birthday[0];
}
```